# how to update $scope object in a view after a promise is resolved in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

i have a simple situation where in the controller I have:

```
$scope.loadEvents = function () {
    var items = listEvents(id);
    items.then(function (data) {
        $scope.test= data;
    });
};
```

In the view I do:

```
<h1>{{test}}</h1>
```

but `$scope.test` is not available yet. If I do `$scope.apply()` I get [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest)

the actual error is that `{{test}}` doesn't show, i guess because is  undefined

any ideas?

Comment: it is not clear with given information! add real html where u using it. Have u confirmed data is not empty or null.

Comment: the actual error is that `{{test}}` doesn't show, i guess because is  undefined

Comment: confirm it by setting test some value in promise  $scope.test= "test data";

Comment: sending `$scope.test= "test data"` directly works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
$scope.test = [];
$scope.loadEvents = function () {
var items = listEvents(id);
items.then(function (data) {
    $scope.test= data;
});
};
```

and in view

```
<h1 ng-if="test">{{test}}</h1>
```

to make it visible only when test is loaded

Comment: for some reason this works, though i don't understand why wont work how i had it